# Why do phones only allow for 5 fingerprints?

Tags: smartphone, fingerprinting

Why do mobile phones only allow for 5 fingerprints for the fingerprint sensor? Is this for security reasons? I am guessing that this was this limitations was for security, opposed to a design choice. Is that right? Why would having more fingerprint options reduce security?